# Fish - remove file before download

Tags: shell-script, fish

I run `fish` shell and it gives an exception when I try to remove a file which is not found. I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

set files "/tmp/*.xlsx"
rm  -f "$files"
echo "$files"
set tmpfile (mktemp -u).xlsx
curl http://localhost:18085/myService -o "$tmpfile"  -s
xdg-open "$tmpfile"
```

When I run it like this than the `files` variable has a complete list of all the patterns. But if one of them cannot be deleted (e.g. still opened) - none would be delete.

I have two questions:

1. What is the best way to delete the files?
2. Since I'm developing sometimes the file isn't downloaded by the `curl`. How to check and only open if the download was successful? (check if exists or check if file size >0 or??)

Comment: maybe instead of `(mktemp -u).xlsx` you mean `$(mktemp -u).xlsx`

Comment: @Romeo, no this is fish. Command substitution has slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're programming fish like you would program sh. Try to "free your mind" of sh limitations.

1. fish variable values are **lists** of strings: I would expand the glob and store the list of files -- i.e. remove the quotes:

   ```bsh
   set files /tmp/*.xlsx
   ```
2. then you provide the expanded list of files to rm

   ```bsh
   rm  -f $files
   ```

Unrelated to the above: you can ask `mktemp` to append the suffix (assuming GNU coreutils)

```bsh
set tmpfile (mktemp -u --suffix=.xlsx)
```

and then `$tmpfile` can be used without quotes.

Comment: Thx for your hints. I'll check tomorrow. You have also an idea how to check properly if the file exists ==> run `xdg-open`?